# Would like to compute the limit of some integral sequence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Consider
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-|x|n}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
$$
The goal of an exercise I am working on is to compute the limit of the the integral above. By intuition it should not converge i.e $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-|x|n}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\infty$.

I think I found an argument proving it, namely, ( I am not sure if this is valid)

Since the integrand is even we have,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-|x|n}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xn}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
$$
Now for some fixed $n\in\mathbb N$ and for all $x\geq 2n$ the following holds,
$$
nx\leq \frac{x^2}{2}
$$
Consequently,
$$
e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\leq e^{-xn}
$$
for all $x\geq 2n$.

Hence,
$$
2\int_{2n}^{\infty}e^{-xn}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\geq2\int_{2n}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{(2n,\infty)}(x)dx=\infty
$$
holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Finally this yields
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-|x|n}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\infty
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and consequently 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-|x|n}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\infty
$$

I am not sure if this argumentation is valid. Could someone look over it?

I am pretty sure there are much better ways to show that the upper limit does not converge and I really would appreciate to see one of those if someone wants to post one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should note that $$e^{\frac12 (-2xn + x^2)} = e^{\frac12 (x-n)^2 - \frac12 n^2} = e^{-n^2/2} e^{\frac{(x-n)^2}{2}}$$

Which means that you can rewrite your integral as: $$2 e^{-n^2/2} \int_0^\infty e^{\frac{(x-n)^2}{2}} dx$$

Now the integrand diverges to infinity for each $n$. Which means each term in your sequence is infinite.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! :-)